# how to show todays data in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub filltable()
        Dim qry As String = "select filename as FileName,filesize as FileSize,time as Time from files"
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        ds = GetQueryResult_Mysql(qry)
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill)
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
            ''For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            ''    Dim fname As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("filename").ToString()
            ''    Dim fsize As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("filesize").ToString()
            ''    Dim ftime As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("time").ToString()

            ''Next
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly review your tag (add sql or mysql) and provide the database structure (create table... and insert into...) of your database. Thank you.

Comment: Your grid is just going to display what's in the `DataTable` so put the data you want displayed in the `DataTable`. That's probably not an answer to the actual question you wanted to ask but, as you haven't actually asked that question, it's answer enough. Try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem and then you will get a specific answer to that question.

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause in the query to filter it by the date, but without knowing which database it's using we can't give you the exact command.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `time` is a time stamp that contains the date too

```
select filename as FileName,filesize as FileSize,time as Time from files WHERE time >= CURDATE()
```

Do please tag your database (and tag the version) next time; we shouldn't have to catch sight of a curiously named method buried in the middle of the code to know you're using MySQL